# Android map doesn't show

Tags: android, dictionary

I'm trying to make a sample map app, but the map doesn't appear on screen like so:

[image: Map on my screen]

I'm following this [example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html) but I don't understand what is wrong so my map to look like this?

I've added the API key like this:

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore \
        -storepass android -keypass android
```

All GPS and Internet permissions are added, and the device is connected to the internet.

Comment: Check your LogCat - most likely, there's an error there indicating that the key you used to sign the app is not registered with google.

Comment: follow this example http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: see this complete example http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/map-api-in-android.html

Comment: ok, i'll check these examples thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are following the example that you posted, you should already have the INTERNET permission added to your code so it is either your android:apiKey or the emulator you are using does not have internet access so check that out

if is a problem with the apiKey this should sort it out
http://informationideas.com/news/2008/11/06/getting-android-emulator-working-with-google-maps-api-key/

Comment: There was an problem with the apikey :)

Answer (score 6):

Either:

- you have the wrong `android:apiKey`, or
- you do not have the `INTERNET` permission, or
- your device or emulator does not have access to the Internet

  or, create new apikey for map and check.

Answer (score 0):

[see this](http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/map-api-in-android.html) complete example

also add following code to **mains.xml**

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:apiKey="----YOUR KEY----"
        android:clickable="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably are signing the apk with a different certificate when debugging, than when exporting it. So you have to have two API keys from google, or you have to sign it with the same certificate, else the apikey is not generated with the correct certificate hash.

Answer (score 0):

user the server API key instead of android API key.